# how to load external .js file in vue 2 component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am working on vue 2 js and I am stuck on js part. I want to use general.js file into my posts.vue file can anyone help me will really appreciate :)

Here is my code :

```
    <template>
        <div>
            <p> {{message}} </p>
        </div>
    </template>

    <script>
        import axios from 'axios';
        import _ from 'lodash';

        export default {
            data() {
                return {
                    message : 'Here is my HTML'    
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Simple as this - ```import './general.js'```

Comment: No @MeetZaveri it gives me an error in npm :(

Comment: Post the error please

Comment: There isn't anything wrong with what you've posted. Are you using a build tool like webpack?

Comment: Can you show us what is defined in `general.js` as well?  i.e. Does it use `export default`  or named exports, etc.

Comment: ERROR in ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib?{"cacheDirectory":true,"presets":[["env",{"modules":false,"targets":{"browsers":["> 2%"],"uglify":true}}],"es2015","stage-3"],"plugins":["transform-object-rest-spread",["transform-runtime",{"polyfill":false,"helpers":false}]]}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./Modules/Press/Assets/js/components/posts/PostForm.vue
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/general.js' in 'E:\project\Assets\js\components\comp'

Comment: Is that the correct path to the general.js file? So it is in the same folder as your vue file?

Comment: @skribe in general.js there is only jquery code

Comment: YES @DigitalDrifter I am using webpack

Comment: @LassiUosukainen I also try with live cdn but its not working

Comment: You probably need to configure your entry point(s) and maybe some aliasing in the webpack config. Which webpack version is it?

Comment: You can't import jQuery code that way.  Are you using this?  
 general.js   https://gist.github.com/tomharrigan/6120534

Comment: @skribe I am using code somthing like that

Answer (score 0):

If you have not already done so you need to use the webpack provide plugin to first include jQuery itself.

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
   $: "jquery",
  jQuery: "jquery"
})
```

More here:  https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/

---

I have always tried to avoid using jquery with vue, but one way I have used jquery on a very limited basis in a component is as follows.

Assume I have a very basic jquery plugin `alertText.js` defined as follows.

```
//define the plugin
$.fn.alertText = function() {
   this.css( "color", "red" );
};
```

Then in my component.vue file I can include the jQuery plugin in much the same way as I would in any page.

```
<template>
  <div>
     <p class="alert-me">this text will be changed to red</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script type="text/javascript" src="alertText.js"></script>

<script>
    $('.alert-me').alertText(); // call the plugin on 'alert-me' class
</script>

<script>
    // define your component script
    export default {
         data():{
              //...
          }
     }
</script>
```

Comment: but how can I use it in .vue file ?